# How to crawl multiple pages in a single spider using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I need to fetch the urls of each product from this page http://www.stalkbuylove.com/new-arrivals/week-2.html#/page/1
and then need to fetch the details of each product from the product link. I am not sure how to do it.

```
import scrapy
import json
import redis

r_server = redis.Redis('localhost')


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["stalkbuylove.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.stalkbuylove.com/new-arrivals/week-2.html#/page/1"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.css('.product-detail-slide'):
            name = sel.xpath('div/a/@title').extract()
            price = sel.xpath('div/span/span/text()').extract()
            productUrl = sel.xpath('div/a/@href').extract()
        request = scrapy.Request(''.join(productUrl), callback=self.parseProductPage)
        r_server.hset(name,"Name",name)
        r_server.hset(name,"Price",price)
        r_server.hset(name,"ProductUrl",productUrl)

        print name, price, productUrl

    def parseProductPage(self, response):
        for sel in response.css('.top-details-product'):    
            availability = sel.xpath('div/link/@href').extract()
            print availability
```

Can anyone help? When I got the product url how to crawl that url? Right now I am calling parseProductUrlPage which is not working.

Comment: Use the crawl spider ;) From docs. `This is the most commonly used spider for crawling regular websites, as it provides a convenient mechanism for following links by defining a set of rules` http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider

Comment: Otherwise your parse method MUST return a Request obejct or an iterable of them.. they will be crawled then.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13508154/not-able-to-follow-link-using-scrapy

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding yield in parse method did the work.